# rabbitmq rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node --offline error when removing node offline

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

When I remove the rabbitmq node offline, the error `mnesia_dir_not_found` is reported, but I have specified the mnesia directory, and the mnesia directory also has permissions.

[image]

[image]